# CSS Resource - Combining literal and runtime substitution

Tags: gwt, cssresource

To enable runtime skinning changes that use browser specific rules,
I need to combine two CSS-resource capabilities - runtime substitution and literal.

For example, to have dynamic button gradient, I would do something like that:

```
button {
   background: literal("-moz-linear-gradient(top, lightBg 0%, darkBg 100%)"); 
   background: literal("-webkit-linear-gradient(top,  lightBg 0%, darkBg 100%)");
   background: literal("-o-linear-gradient(top, lightBg 0%, darkBg 100%)");
   background: literal("-ms-linear-gradient(top,  lightBg 0%, darkBg 100%)");
   background: linear-gradient(top,  lightBg 0%, darkBg 100%); 
}
```

where lightBg and darkBg are evaluated at runtime using @eval.

The problem is that GWT doesn't parse the literal string, so it doesn't evaluate these two values.
See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource)

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can concatenate literals and regular css, which can look something like

```
background: literal("-moz-linear-gradient(") top lightBg 0, darkBg 100 literal(")");
```

Not sure if that last literal is needed or not.

Comment: Works! and yes, the last literal is needed.
Here is the correct version (with some small fixes for FF):
`background: literal("-moz-linear-gradient(") top, lightBg 0%, darkBg 100% literal(")");`

Comment: Weird, I could have sworn I typed those percent signs the first time... Glad you got it working!

Comment: This workaround with the 'magic literals' is no longer needed as of gwt 2.5-rc1.  You can simply substitute as you did in your question, and it will just work.

Here's the test case gwt team is using with an example of gradients http://gwt-code-reviews.appspot.com/1735804/diff/8001/user/test/com/google/gwt/resources/client/test.css